# What can I do when I or someone in my party falls through a floating mat?

Tags: water, risk-managment, swamps

Once, I had the opportunity to walk on a [floating mat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_mat) on a guided tour with a nature organisation in [De Wieden](https://nl.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Wieden) (Dutch: *trilveen*).  On the surface, it looked (to my amateur eye) exactly like other peat, but walking on it felt like walking on a huge trampoline.  Where I stood, I sank about half a metre down along with the moss, and the whole land in a radius of around 1–2 metre around me sank with me.  When poking a long stick into the soil, we noticed that after a metre or so, resistance become zero: evidently, these mosses were floating on water.

Although rare, such floating mats exist throughout different regions in Northern Europe.  I believe I have passed over one in Sarek National Park in Sweden, with no surface water in sight nearby but the entire pond covered I only realised it once I was in the middle of it (or at least I think it was a floating mat; I have no independent confirmation).  I imagine falling through is an effective way to vanish without a trace, swallowed by the Earth with the land closing above me.  I don't know if this is possible.  The popular image of someone vanishing completely in quicksand is mostly wrong, as one doesn't normally sink beyond ones centre of mass.  How are the real dangers for floating mats?  Can one fall through?  Can one get stuck?  Can I pull myself out if I do?  Can I pull out my partner safely?

In some parts of the world floating mats are only known to exist in access-controlled nature reserves, so anyone respecting the rules is very unlikely to accidentally walk on any; but that may not be the case everywhere.

The English language Wikipedia article states it is possible to "drown" in floating mats, but is unspecific on what this means: vanishing *underneath* the floating mat, or getting stuck in the floating mat.

Comment: I checked out the Dutch wikipedia page on the 'trilveen' and it just stated that you are not allowed to walk on it as it is so easy to damage. So no 'what to do if you do fall through.'

Comment: @Willeke Being not allowed to walk on it is hard to respect unless it is clearly identifiable. I wouldn't walk on it on purpose, nor would I walk on quicksand on purpose, but accidents happen. I'd obviously not continue if there was a sign that said *trilveen*, but as stated, when I did walk on it with a guided tour I would have never identified it myself.

Comment: In the Netherlands these areas are likely off limits because you are not allowed into the nature area without a guide (which means the guide may have permission to ignore the rules)  or it is a 'stay on the paths' area. These rules do not work/count out of the Netherlands.

Comment: @Willeke Ok, then in The Netherlands this is unlikely to be a problem for anyone respecting the rules.  I've heard trilveen also exists in Sareks Nationalpark in Sweden, where access is allowed but trails are prohibited, meaning hiking off-rail is effectively mandatory... (I did nearly get stuck in quicksand there once, and may have crossed trilveen once, but I'm not sure)

Comment: That is why I wrote a comment, not an answer.

Comment: The book [Quetico, near to Nature's Heart](https://books.google.com/books?id=tS-JyAvVGr0C&pg=PA191&lpg=PA191&dq=snowshoes,+floating+bog&source=bl&ots=2eSUW98pwh&sig=ACfU3U0hHUirqPO56znAhCQHleXxU82tsg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjXjM3bs8rnAhWXknIEHa1PDdgQ6AEwAHoECAgQAQ#v=onepage&q=snowshoes%2C%20floating%20bog&f=false) recommends wearing snowshoes when walking on a floating bog.

Comment: @ab2MonicaNotForgotten Thanks for the link.  It was a lovely read!  Alas, although I'm not an ultralight backpacker, I *don't* usually take my snowshoes in a summer or autumn hike :-)

Answer (score 3):

The risk of drowning by falling through a floating mat like you describe is very low - the resistance provided by the vegetation of the mat itself and the water beneath it is very likely to prevent you becoming fully submerged. The few records of drownings in bogs that I can find suggest that children are the usual victim, possibly due to their reduced ability to swim, their tendency to panic, and the speed at which they become exhausted. There is also a lot of evidence that bog bodies found preserved in bogs died of unnatural causes and were buried in the bog after their death, rather than dying of drowning as a result of falling in.

So if you do fall in then you should expect to climb out without too much difficulty. Treat it like falling through ice - kick your legs to hold you higher out of the water whilst crawling forwards onto the surrounding ground. Keep yourself spread out on your front to spread your weight out over as much of the ground as possible, reducing the risk of breaking back through. Discard any items that are unbalancing you or weighing you down. If you are carrying walking poles and have miraculously managed not to drop them then you may find these useful to give you more purchase, but the ground is likely soft enough for this not to be a problem.

A far more dangerous, and likely, scenario is falling into snow-covered water courses and bogs in winter conditions. This is more dangerous because the snow-cover provides far less resistance and there can be a substantial gap between the snow and the water, meaning that you are more likely to fully submerge. The temperature of the water is also more likely to elicit a shock response, which can inhibit your ability to self-rescue.

Floating mats created by woody debris in rivers are also more dangerous as they're made up of more massive material which may cause you injury and is more likely to rearrange as a result of disturbance, but they're also very easy to avoid.

You then have to consider how you respond to suddenly and unexpectedly being very wet and cold. Take spare layers in a dry-bag in your rucksack that you can wear if you get soaked (replace wet clothing if you can, if you can't you can add a moisture barrier over the top of it). If you have a communication device, like a phone, then make sure that it is suitably waterproofed. Leave instructions with someone you trust who is not in your party with your route plan and your expected return/contact time so that they can contact the emergency services if you do not arrive.

I question the sense of wearing snow-shoes to walk on a floating bog (although they may offer significant protection from falling into snow covered water courses!) - that seems like a good way to trip and break and ankle, whilst simultaneously making it harder to crawl out of the bog if you did fall in.